# How to convert url segment to querystring with Nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I whould like this simple rewrite rule:

```
http://example.com/8743b52063cd84097a65d1633f5c74f5?param1=999&param2=2222
```

to be redirected to:

```
http://example.com/index.php?param1=999&param2=2222&hash=8743b52063cd84097a65d1633f5c74f5
```

The following is my default location:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

How can I achieve this using Nginx rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [rewrite statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite):

```
rewrite "^/(\w{32})$" /index.php?hash=$1 last;
```

Or, within a [location block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

```
location ~ "^/(?<hash>\w{32})$" {
    rewrite ^ /index.php?hash=$hash last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Richard!! That worked! What if I want to take the entire segment no matter how many characters have on it?

Comment: You probably want to set minimum and maximum limits, otherwise other URIs may start looking like a valid hash. But `\w{16,32}` would match an alphanumeric sequence of between 16 and 32 characters for example. See the [quick reference here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).

Comment: Ok, I understand Richard, that make sense. I'll take a look at the reference. Thanks for your support!